# Marching Squares Algorithm's bit shifting step

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

I am currently implementing the [Marching Squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_squares) for calculating contour curves and I had a question regarding the usage of bit shifting as mentioned here

> Compose the 4 bits at the corners of the cell to build a binary index: walk around the cell in a clockwise direction appending the bit to the index, using bitwise OR and left-shift, from most significant bit at the top left, to least significant bit at the bottom left. The resulting 4-bit index can have 16 possible values in the range 0–15.

I have height data that I place on corners of each vertex at a specified (x,y). Then I convert this height data into 0s and 1s by performing a check to see whether this height data is greater or lesser than a specified isovalue(say contour level). Now the vertexes are either 0s or 1s. What is the purpose of the next step i.e. calculating the 4-bit index by traversing  in a clockwise direction ?

Comment: The very next bullet point on that page you're reading tells you what that index is used for.

Comment: The point is still that the lookup table contains the answer, so you need something that can function as an index into that table. E: though I think that step 1 is just needlessly wordy and contains irrelevant details, we might as well say "concatenate the bits".

Comment: @harold - ok I do not understand that. I have searched on google but it is not clear to me how calculating the binary index by bit shifting connects the points of equal height. I have zeroes and ones - now I am bit shifting them. How does it lead me to finding points of equal height ?

Comment: Then you have a number. The table then contains, at the position of that number, a description of where to put lines that approximately follow isolines.

Comment: @harold - why specifically bit shifting ? Why not some other transformation of 0s and 1s ? It maybe helpful to show this with an example.

Comment: It's the most obvious way to do it. Consider the analogous case if you had some decimal digits and wanted to make a unique number for every combination of them: would you concatenate them? Probably, right? That's what's happening here too but in binary.

Comment: @YvesDaoust four values yes

Comment: @gansub you deleted before I submit my comment to your last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47029796/2521214)... For straight line the radius is infinity so it will cross any grid cell size. To handle that you should limit it with some max value which is bigger than any sane usable value for the setup you are using. What that is is hard to say without background knowledge about what for you use the osculating circle. (For example I set tool normal with it for specific machinery  so my max value is determined by mechanical properties of machine ...)

Comment: @gansub for the osculating circle or the contour itself you do not need any grid ... do you mean bounding box instead? You can always resize (enlarge) it to match the new contour ...

Comment: @gansub ah spherical coordinate angles wrap ... You should allow angles beond those limits and after computation convert them to normal ranges....

Comment: @gansub I would go for math SE .... but if you know some GIS related sites they would be even better I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of composing a four bit code is simply to identify the configuration, one among sixteen cases.

You could very well use four nested if/then/else statements instead.